# SELECT count from table where datetime is today in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named tickets and ticket_updates

in ticket_updates there is a datetime column, and tickets.ticketnumber is equal to ticket_updates.ticketnumber

There is multiple rows in ticket_updates per each row in tickets

I want to select the number of rows added in tickets based on the datetime column in ticket_updates

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as counter 
from ticket_updates 
where DATE(datetime) = '2014-11-03' 
group by ticketnumber 
limit 0,1
```

but it returns 3 which is wrong, as 8 rows have been added in the tickets table today

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `group by` if you want the total:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as counter 
from ticket_updates 
where DATE(datetime) = '2014-11-03' ;
```

Use the `group by` if you want the number of updates per `ticketnumber`.

Use `count(distinct ticketnumber)` if you want the number of different ticket numbers changed today.

EDIT:

If you want today's date and you want to be able to take advantage of an index, then try:

```
where datetime >= date(now()) and datetime < date(now()) + interval 1 day
```

Comment: I would also possibly suggest using `WHERE datetime BETWEEN `2014-11-03 00:00:00' AND `2014-11-03 23:59:59'` so as to leverage index on that column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join two tables like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(ticketnumber) AS counter
FROM tickets WHERE ticketnumber  in (
             SELECT distinct ticketnumber 
             FROM ticket_updates 
             WHERE DATE(datetime) = '2014-11-03')
```

Comment: forgot to mention, there are rows added in ticket_updates which may not be on the same day. I want to only show number of rows where the first row was added in ticket_updates

Comment: so for example, the rows could be added in tickets and ticket_updates on 2014-11-01 but an extra row may have been added to ticket_updates on 2014-11-03 - i dont want to count this latest row added

Comment: So your could would always be 1. So your output would be: T1 1, T2 1, T3 1 is that what you are expecting? See above query if that works for you?

Comment: ah, let me try again. i dont think im making much sense :) - So there are two tables, for each one row in tickets there could be 5+ rows in ticket_updates. Everytime a row is inserted into tickets, a row is added in ticket_updates with a datetime. I want to show the number of rows added in tickets using the datetime from ticket_updates table but i need to count only one row from ticket_updates not all rows for the selected date (tickets.ticketnumber will always equal ticket_updates.ticketnumber) - i want to show the total count and not the count per ticketnumber

Comment: t.datetime does not exist

Comment: if i remove AND  tu.datetime = t.datetime its returning 10 rows (should return 8) i think i just need to limit the rows it returns in ticket_updates per ticketnumber. limit to return 1 row per ticketnumber

Comment: looks like the one but i think its trying to load too many rows maybe? its returning an internal server error

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, probably this is what you need:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
 (SELECT ticketnumber
 FROM ticket_updates 
 GROUP BY ticketnumber
 HAVING DATE(min(datetime)) = '2014-11-03' ) as `t1`
```